# What is the $\lim_{t\to \infty} u(1,t)$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u(x,t)$ be a solution of $u_t-u_{xx}=0$

we are given the following additional information. $$u(x,0)=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}$$

and $u(x,t)$ is bounded.

**I want to find the $\lim_{t\to \infty} u(1,t)$**

I know the general solution of heat equation is given by $$u(x,t)= \sum {B_n}\sin \left( {\frac{{n\pi x}}{L}} \right){{\bf{e}}^{ - k{{\left( {\frac{{n\pi }}{L}} \right)}^2}\,t}}\hspace{0.25in}n = 1,2,3, \ldots$$

so we have $$u(x,0)=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}=\sum{B_n}\sin \left( {\frac{{n\pi x}}{L}} \right)$$

How should I proceed after this step.

P.S. This was asked in GATE 2006 Mathematical Sciences. Key says the answer is -1/2. Since no boundry country was given(either the question is wrong or we just have to assume the standard problem \begin{align*}& \frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial t}} = k\frac{{{\partial ^2}u}}{{\partial {x^2}}}\\ & u\left( {x,0} \right) = f\left( x \right)\hspace{0.25in}u\left( {0,t} \right) = 0\hspace{0.25in}u\left( {L,t} \right) = 0\end{align*}

Comment: The solution that you mentioned only works for the problem mentioned in the bottom, i.e., with zero-boundary condition. For the problem only with initial condition, the solution of a heat equation will be written in terms of the convolution with the fundamental solution (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Fundamental_solutions)). Now, as for your question, the solution is given by $$u(x,t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-(x-x')^2/4t}u(x',0)\,\mathrm{d}x',$$ and using this, we can show that the limit of $u(1,t)$ as $t\to\infty$ is $0$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks a lot. Options given in the question booklet are $-1/2,1/2,-1,1$ so can I assume with 100% guarantee that question is indeed wrong(I mean the options).

Comment: I also suspect so. As for an intuitive explanation, recall that heat equation smooths out the initial data in such a way that mass is conserved. But since the initial data $u(x, 0) = \operatorname{tanh}(x)$ is an odd function, the positive part and the negative part will begin to cancel each other as time evolves. This can also be glimpsed if we replace the initial condition by a similar-looking function $u(x, 0) = \operatorname{erf}(x)$, where the solution now takes an explicit form $u(x, t) = \operatorname{erf}(x/\sqrt{1+4t})$ and this decays to $0$ as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: Oh I see. The intuitive idea you mentioned clears everything. Thanks for taking time and helping me out. Cheers.